# Vim map that takes char as an argument

Tags: vim

I am trying to make a snippet for printing line of characters. For example, l50= to print 50 = signs.
So, is it possible to define such remap or I am asking for too much?

Comment: What have you already tried for yourself?

Comment: Native behavior already supports it without a map.  `50i=<Esc>` will do it, after a brief timeout.  Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: Thank you, Michael. It's what I wanted.